# How can I configure a plugin in RxDB?

Tags: javascript, rxdb

I added the ajv validation plugin through the standard way:

```
import { RxDBAjvValidatePlugin } from 'rxdb/plugins/ajv-validate';

addRxPlugin(RxDBAjvValidatePlugin);
```

and now see the following error:

> Uncaught Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "encrypted"

While my schema does not contain the `encrypted` keyword at all, it is [allowable](https://rxdb.info/rx-schema.html#encryption) by RxDB. So, the ajv validation does not let this rule pass in strict mode.

However, it is possible to [tinker around](https://ajv.js.org/strict-mode.html#prohibit-ignored-keywords) with ajv configuration and prevent the appearence of this error (for example, by setting `ajv.addKeyword("encrypted")`). The question is how to do it (provide the configuration to the plugin) using RxDB?